# Bootstrap typehead not opening pop up on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using typehead bootstrap with angular js on click I am calling an popup with id tag , how to call the same popup when I press the enter key.

```
<div>
    <form role="search">
        <input class="typeahead tt-query" id="enter" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" ng-model="searchAllBreakfast" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'enter...'" placeholder="enter...">
   </form>
</div>
```

In plugin I modified

```
e=function(a){return"<p data-toggle=modal data-   target=#getIndividualfood>"+a[d]+"</p>"},e}
```

So, whenever I click the element from list its calling the popup with id #getIndividualfood but its not coming at enter key press

kindly,some one help me to do that

Comment: Try `<form ng-submit="launchThePopup()">`

Comment: Define "not working". Do you have any errors in the console? Is the `launchThePopup()` function not triggering on submit? What did you do? Where is your code? Do you alert something in that function? "Not working is just a _little bit_ insufficient to help you out.